# Increment one value in a text line, using script

Tags: batch, sed, awk, plaintext

I have a text file as input.  I need to filter that through some program, SED, AWK, whatever, where i need to increment a value in a particular line every time i run the script.

What's the best way of doing it?

Sample text:

```
File Type
Rev 100
data a
data b
file loc
comment line
eof
```

only the "`Rev 100`" should change to "`Rev 101`"

Comment: provide a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp textfile /tmp/textfile
awk '{if ($1 == "Rev") printf("%s %d\n", $1, $2 + 1); else print $0;}' /tmp/textfile > textfile
```

Answer (score 3):

awk:

```
/^Rev / {
  print "Rev " $2+1
  next
}

{
  print
}
```